# How to hide a view below toolbar on list view scroll?

Tags: android, scroll, android-toolbar

I have a LinearLayout with toolbar, a view below toolbar(similar to toolbar) and a list view below the view.

I'm able to hide the toolbar when list view is scrolled using CollapsingToolbarLayout, is there any way I can hide the view below toolbar without hiding the toolbar when the listview is scrolled?

Answer (score 0):

```
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);

listView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
int mLastFirstVisibleItem = 0;

@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {   }           

@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {    
    if (view.getId() == listView.getId()) {
        final int currentFirstVisibleItem = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();

        if (currentFirstVisibleItem > mLastFirstVisibleItem) {

            view.setVisibility(View.GONE);//view is the refrene to ur desired view which u want to hide
        } else if (currentFirstVisibleItem < mLastFirstVisibleItem) {

            view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        mLastFirstVisibleItem = currentFirstVisibleItem;
    }               
}
});
```

Comment: this code will hide the actionbar. I want to hide the view which is below the actionbar.

Comment: the animation wont be smooth. It looks glitchy.